# Appium - Java, How to automate swipe in android?

Tags: java, android, appium

Trying to automate android app using appium, when entered the below code for swipe giving ----

```
TouchAction io.appium.java_client.TouchAction.press(WebElement el) 
@Deprecated
TouchAction ac = new TouchAction(driver);
ac.press(436,652).moveTo(-311,-14).release().perform();
```

What can be used to swipe?

Answer (score 0):

The use of coordinates or wait times has been deprecated. You're now supposed to use [ActionOptions](https://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/touch/ActionOptions.html). In the case of points, they're called [PointOptions](https://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/touch/offset/PointOption.html).

Comment: Neither ActionOptions nor PointOptions exist in the C# driver. I suppose this is a feature which exists only in the Java beta version.

Answer (score 0):

TouchAction works for me when giving it elements to start and stop the swiping at:

```
WebElement start = driver.findElement(By.id("xxxxxx"));
WebElement stop = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xxxxxx"));
TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver);
action.longPress(start).moveTo(stop).release().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `waitAction` in the following code is crucial to properly implementing a swipe (that took me a couple hours of investigation to learn).

```
public static void actionSwipeLeft(AndroidDriver driver)
{
    Dimension dims = driver.manage().window().getSize();
    int       x    = (int) (dims.getWidth() * .5);
    int       y    = (int) (dims.getHeight() * .8);

    int       endX = 0;

    System.out.println("Swiping left.");

    new TouchAction(driver)
            .press(new PointOption().withCoordinates(x, y))
            .waitAction(new WaitOptions().withDuration(Duration.ofMillis(500)))
            .moveTo(new PointOption().withCoordinates(endX, y))
            .release()
            .perform();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think one of commentors, Mike, might be right about wait times being deprecated. (The sources are all discombobulated.) This is the code that I use. Hope it helps.

```java
new TouchAction(driver).longPress(PointOption.point(x, y)).moveTo(PointOption.point(x, y)).release().perform();
```