# how to perform vertical swipe in android for appium

Tags: appium

I am using Appium 1.7 and Android 8 on real device. But I am stuck with swipe up. tried with different combinations. Could you please provide an easy code for swipe functionality?

Tried:

```
private void scrollDown() {
    //if pressX was zero it didn't work for me
    int pressX = driver.manage().window().getSize().width / 2;
    // 4/5 of the screen as the bottom finger-press point
    int bottomY = driver.manage().window().getSize().height * 4/5;
    // just non zero point, as it didn't scroll to zero normally
    int topY = driver.manage().window().getSize().height / 8;
    //scroll with TouchAction by itself
    scroll(pressX, bottomY, pressX, topY);
}

/*
 * don't forget that it's "natural scroll" where 
 * fromY is the point where you press the and toY where you release it
 */
private void scroll(int fromX, int fromY, int toX, int toY) {
    TouchAction touchAction = new TouchAction(driver);
    touchAction.longPress(fromX, fromY).moveTo(toX, toY).release().perform();
}
```

But no luck..!!

Answer (score 1):

```
private void scroll(int fromX, int fromY, int toX, int toY) {
   TouchAction touchAction = new TouchAction(driver);
   touchAction.tap(fromX, fromY).waitAction(1000).moveTo(toX, 
   toY).release().perform();
}
```

you have to wait after pressing.
This will work
Can use this to swipe in any direction from point a to point b

Comment: do we need to pass coordinate values directly here? int fromX, int fromY, int toX, int toY

Comment: Tap() is wrong. But it is correct that a Wait is required. Correct would be Press() and then Wait()

Answer (score 1):

This gives me the solution:

```
TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver); 
action.longPress(bottomElement).moveTo(topElement).release().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this question: [Appium - Java, How to automate swipe in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47730334/appium-java-how-to-automate-swipe-in-android), the use of coordinates is Deprecated. I posted an answer there with the code that works for me in this case

Comment: This answer is wrong. Neither ActionOptions nor PointOptions exist in the C# driver. I suppose this is a feature which exists only in the Java beta version.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform scroll / swipe up action with below code:

```
Dimension size = this.driver.manage ()
    .window ()
    .getSize ();
int startX = size.getWidth () / 2;
int startY = size.getHeight () / 2;
int endX = 0;
int endY = (int) (startY * -1 * 0.75);
TouchAction action = new TouchAction (this.driver);
action.press (startX, startY)
    .moveTo (endX, endY)
    .release ()
    .perform ();
```

You can tweak the code to perform left, down and right swipe. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: This gives a negative value."int endY = (int) (startY * -1 * 0.75);". Hence coordinate not available exception throwing.

Comment: If you are using 5.0 or above of java client then this will work fine as I'm using it in my framework and this same code works fine. Basically -ve endY will specify the Appium to move from center of the screen to upper border of the screen.

Comment: Im using Java 1.8 and it gives -ve value.

Comment: Can you confirm you are using the complete code which I posted or you modified it. If you modified it then can you post your version of the code?

Comment: I tried with your entire code.

driver.swipe(size.width/2,  size.height-1, size.width/2,200  , 2000);
This driver.swipe is not working for me. It shows 'Add cast to 'driver' also scrollTo also not working. Can you advise me on this.

Comment: Don't use driver.swipe method, use TouchAction class as I have done the same in my code. Swipe method is not available in Appium since 5.0.4 so you also need to use Appium java-client 5.0.4 in order for your swipe to work. Just copy paste my code and it will work.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Y coordinate value should be equal or greater than zero

when executed the code:
'Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
   
   int startX = size.getWidth () / 2;
   int startY = size.getHeight () / 2;
   int endX = 0;
   int endY = (int) (startY * -1 * 0.75);
   @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
 TouchAction action = new TouchAction (driver);
   action.press (startX, startY).moveTo (endX,endY).release().perform ();'

Comment: Can you post a gist link to your test file so I can see what is the problem?

Comment: What version of java-client you are using?

Comment: Your code is working at my end as well as my friends end. The problem here seems to be Appium version. Try with latest stable version for both server as well as java binding and then let me know.

Comment: Currently i am using
java-client-6.0.0-BETA1.
Could you please provide me the exact link to download latest stable version for both server as well as java binding?

Comment: First thing to keep in mind, never use a product which is in beta phase. You can download latest stable version (5.0.4) from https://github.com/appium/java-client/releases or you can just use Maven dependency with version 5.0.4. Hope this will help you.

Comment: If you want you can use my Appium wrapper framework which can be found at https://github.com/WasiqB/coteafs-appium. It's very easy to use. To get started with it, have a look at it's wiki page.

Comment: I have replaced java client file with 5.04. version as you mentioned and now my swipe issue got resolved and working perfectly. Tonnes of thanks for the help.. :)

Answer (score 0):

i have used the below code to Swipe / Scroll and it is working perfectly
Code to Swipe UP

```
public boolean swipeFromUpToBottom() 
    {

     try {
          JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
          HashMap<String, String> scrollObject = new HashMap<String, String>();
          scrollObject.put("direction", "up");
          js.executeScript("mobile: scroll", scrollObject);
          System.out.println("Swipe up was Successfully done.");
        }
           catch (Exception e) 
            {
                System.out.println("swipe up was not successfull");
            }   
        return false;               
    }
```

Code to Swipe DOWN

```
  public boolean swipeFromBottomToUp() 
    {       
      try  {
              JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
              HashMap<String, String> scrollObject = new HashMap<String,String>);
              scrollObject.put("direction", "down");
              js.executeScript("mobile: scroll", scrollObject);
              System.out.println("Swipe down was Successfully done");
        }
           catch (Exception e) 
            {
                System.out.println("swipe down was not successfull");
            }   
        return false;                   
    }
```

Code for carousel images swipe

```
public boolean swipeImages() 
    {       
      try   {
                  WebElement pageIndicator = driver.findElement(page_indicator);
                  String pageString= pageIndicator.getAttribute("value");
                  int length = pageString.length();
                  String count_string= pageString.substring(length-2, length).trim();
                  int count = Integer.parseInt(count_string);
                  System.out.println("Number of Image available to Swipe: "+count);
                  for (int i=0; i<=count; i++){          
                          JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
                          HashMap<String, String> scrollObject = new HashMap<String, String>();
                          scrollObject.put("direction", "right");
                          js.executeScript("mobile: scroll", scrollObject);       
           }
           System.out.println("Swipe Successfully");
        }
           catch (Exception e) 
            {
                System.out.println("Image swipe was not successfull");
            }   
        return false;                   
    }
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use the below method to Swipe and Scroll

```
public void scrollUpTo() {
    Dimension size;
    size = getCurrentDriver().manage().window().getSize();
    double screenHeightStart = size.getHeight() * 0.5;
    int scrollStart = (int) screenHeightStart;
    double screenHeightEnd = size.getHeight() * 0.2;
    int scrollEnd = (int) screenHeightEnd;
    swipe(50, scrollStart, 0, scrollEnd, 2000);
}
```

Use the below method to swipe Right

```
public void initWidthSize() {
    Dimension size = getCurrentDriver().manage().window().getSize();
    startx = (int) (size.width * 0.90);
    endx = (int) (size.width * 0.10);
    starty = size.height / 2;
}

public void swiperToRightWithCoordinates(int starty) {
    initWidthSize();
    swipe(endx, starty, startx, starty, 1000);
}
```

use the below method to swipe Left

```
public void swiperToLeftWithCoordinates(int starty) {
    initWidthSize();
    swipe(startx, starty, endx, starty, 1000);
}

public void swiperToLeftWithBothCoordinates(int startx, int starty) {
    initWidthSize();
    swipe(startx, starty, endx, starty, 1000);
}

public void swiperToLeftWithTextContainsAndCoordinates(String name, int count, int coordinate) {
    int i = 0;
    do {
        boolean isPresent = getCurrentDriver()
                .findElement(By
                        .xpath("//XCUIElementTypeStaticText[@value='" + name + "']"))
                .isDisplayed();
        if (isPresent) {
            break;
        } else {
            swiperToLeftWithCoordinates(coordinate);
        }
        i++;
    } while (i <= count);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

### Use this latest code this is working for Appium Java Client 7.2.0

```
//Method - 1 
public void voidSwipevertical(AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver, double startPercentage, double endPercentage){
    Dimension size=driver.manage().window().getSize();
    int width=(int)(size.getWidth()/2);
    int startPoint=(int)(size.getHeight()*startPercentage);

    int endPoint=(int)(size.getHeight()*endPercentage);
    new TouchAction(driver).press(PointOption.point(width, startPoint)).waitAction().moveTo(PointOption.point(width, endPoint)).release().perform();

}

//Method - 2 
public void voidSwipevertical2(AndroidDriver<WebElement> driver, double startPercentage, double endPercentage){
    Dimension size=driver.manage().window().getSize();
    int width=(int)(size.getWidth()/2);
    int startPoint=(int)(size.getHeight()*startPercentage);

    int endPoint=(int)(size.getHeight()*endPercentage);
    new TouchAction(driver).press(PointOption.point(width, startPoint)).moveTo(PointOption.point(width, endPoint)).release().perform();
}

//Method - 3
public void voidSwipevertical3(AndroidDriver<WebElement> driver, double startPercentage, double endPercentage) throws Exception{
    Dimension size=driver.manage().window().getSize();
    int width=(int)(size.getWidth()/2);
    int startPoint=(int)(size.getHeight()*startPercentage);

    int endPoint=(int)(size.getHeight()*endPercentage);

    TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver); 
    action.longPress(PointOption.point(width, startPoint)).moveTo(PointOption.point(width, endPoint)).release().perform();
}
```