# How to swipe horizontally in Appium , As swipe is deprecated in Appium Any replacement for swipe

Tags: appium-android

private static void Add_Feed() throws InterruptedException {

```
TouchActions action = new TouchActions(driver);
action.press(10, 10);
action.move(50, 50);
action.perform();
Thread.sleep(10000);
```

As swipe is deprecated in Appium, i m using this

But error message displayed as,

> java.lang.ClassCastException: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.interactions.HasTouchScreen

Comment: This is already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47791276/5320558

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
new TouchAction(driver).press(startX, startY).waitAction(Duration.ofMillis(duration)).moveTo(endX, endY).release().perform();
```

Make sure you use the import java.time.Duration; for Duration class

Answer (score 0):

```
    new TouchAction(getDriver())
            .press(point(startX, startY))
            .waitAction(waitOptions(Duration.ofSeconds(1)))
            .moveTo(point(startX, endY)).release().perform();
```